# pl/sql query to get n records at a time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**ref_number** is a column in the xxtable which has same values many times. For every 5 values I need to have the alias **type** increased by 1 --  max **type** 100

```
**Select type,ref_number
 from (select '70' type
        , ref_number
        from xxtable)**
```

Result of the query should look like this

```
type       ref_number
----       ----------
70         1001
70         1001
70         1001
70         1001
70         1001
71         1001
71         1001
71         1001
71         1001
71         1001
72         1001
72         1001
72         1001
 .
 .
 .
100
```

Comment: You should specify your query more precisely. Should column `type` increase after *distinct* 5 `ref_number` values (which can span more rows) or just after each 5 consecutive *same* `ref_number`s? What's the limit 100 referring to - `type` or `ref_number` (seems redundant to me)? Example of sample data and expected output is welcome. (BTW: I suspect this problem as solvable with Oracle analytical function without need of PLSQL, depending on your potential clarification.)

Comment: I have edited my post to make it clear

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, you want this:

```
select least(trunc(70+count(*)/5), 100), ref_number
from xxtable
group by ref_number
```

Edit:
So, I think that should work

```
select least(trunc(70+(row_number() over (partition by ref_number order by ref_number)-1)/5), 100), ref_number
from xxtable
```

Edit:
This should work:

```
select type, LISTAGG(ref_number, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ref_number) 
from(
select least(trunc(70+(row_number() over (partition by ref_number order by ref_number)-1)/5), 100) type, ref_number
from xxtable)
group by type, ref_number
```

Note: I can't try it out, so I might have put another bug in there.

Comment: Kindly notifying of two small bugs: missing `order by` in `over` and wrong arithmetic since `row_number()` is 1-based. Also still is not clear if `type` should turn back to 70 if `ref_number` changes (my answer solves this alternative).

Comment: You are right about the 2 bugs, but I think, you are making it too complicated with your last point. I don't think it is meant this way and if it is, you could just drop the partition by-part

Comment: Thanks for the code it works fine , can I display as listagg for the ref_number as 70 10011001100110011001 next line 71 10011001100110011001 Thanks!

Comment: Ok user2179887, I stated my answer is relevant only upon condition of changing `ref_number`. Good to hear simple solution suffices but I disagree with affirmation that dropping `partition by` would suffice - it wouldn't "reset" `type` on the boundary of `ref_number` areas.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't specified if `type` is increasing for different `ref_number`. If not, user2179887's idea suffices. If yes, another logic must be added. I'm afraid it's not possible without multiple ("nested") usage of analytic function:

```
with xxtable as (
  select column_value as ref_number
  from table(sys.KU$_OBJNUMSET(
    1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,
    1002,1002,1002,
    1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,
    1004,
    1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,
    1006
  ))
)
select
  70 + trunc(((row_number() over (partition by x.ref_number order by null)) - 1)/5) as user2179887_corrected_type,
  x.ref_number,
  70 + trunc(((row_number() over (partition by x.ref_number order by null)) - 1)/5) + nvl(g.gs,0) as increasing_type
from xxtable x
join (
  select
    ref_number,
    sum(trunc((count(*) + 4) / 5))
      over (order by ref_number rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as gs
  from xxtable
  group by ref_number
) g on g.ref_number = x.ref_number
```

Explanation:

- `with`-clause is only for purpose of data simulation in Oracle built-in collection, you can safely copy off only rest of query
- for every unique `ref_number`, the `g` subselect precomputes contribution of all rows with this `ref_number` to result `type`
- analytical `sum over` collects these sums for previous values (`1 preceding` in windowing clause)
- condition 'type max 100' omitted for brevity

I think this is kind of beyond the margin of comprehensibility of analytical functions. Maybe using `model` clause could give more readable result. Anyway, thanks for interesting problem, made me learn more about analytical functions :-).